# Remove entire days reports from google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

We migrated our ecommerce store. We did an order import into our new store of all our previous orders. We forgot to disable google analytics product tracking during this time. This somehow caused it to show mass amounts of profit/data for the day of the order migration.

I am wondering if we can just remove the entire days anlytical findings from showing in our reports?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have used the `data import` feature you just need to delete that import from the relevant option in the Property settings, otherwise if you have imported via data transmission (measurement protocol) you cannot delete them.